# Using CLASSPATH, Java and compiling from zsh

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, classpath, zsh

I'm trying to compile and run Java files from a workspace at the following directory:

/Users/raph/Java/Workspace/COMP30820>

Inside the directory are src and bin directories, and the src folder contains my packages. If I run the .java files in VSCode using the integrated terminal, it finds my imported packages, but if I run it from Terminal using zsh (or bash) the packages aren't found. I'm aware this is something to do with the CLASSPATH, but I've tried as many different ways of exporting it in the zshrc file and I'm still having no luck. My JAVA_HOME variable is being exported correctly.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
package test_import;

import test_package.Test;


public class Importer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test i = new Test();
    i.hello();
}
}
```

Which is using this package:

```
package test_package;

public class Test {

    public static void hello(){
        System.out.println("Hello there");
    }
}
```

both test_import and test_package are directly inside the src folder.

If I then run Importer.java from the test_import directory, I expect to see "Hello there" printed.

If I run this in VS Code it works, but from any other terminal it doesn't, and I get the following error:

```
Importer.java:3: error: package test_package does not exist
import test_package.Test;
                   ^
Importer.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
        Test i = new Test();
        ^
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class Importer
Importer.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
        Test i = new Test();
                     ^
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class Importer
3 errors
error: compilation failed
```

Is anyone able to tell me how to correctly set the classpath in this instance?

Comment: `export CLASSPATH="/Users/raph/Java/Workspace/COMP30820/bin"`

Comment: Thanks for this - I tried it and I'm now getting this error: error: class found on application class path: test_import.Importer

Comment: What command are you running? What do you expect it to do? What is the full error? And where are you running the command? Please edit the question.

Comment: I've made an edit, but the error written above is the full error. I'm running the command Importer.java in the test_import directory.

Comment: If I am in the workspace directory and I run java test_import/Importer it is now working, so thanks Elliott that must be to do with the classpath. Is it generally the case that you should run modules that include imports from the workspace dir?

Comment: You should be running `java test_import.Importer`; and the directory you run it from won't matter. You're specifying a **file**; not a class.

Comment: Thanks so much! Hugely helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Elliot - "You should be running java test_import.Importer; and the directory you run it from won't matter. You're specifying a file; not a class."

The correct way to run the file was java test_import.Importer.